# Enabling printk functionality in mcount registered function

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I registered my function to `mcount` similar to `ftrace` and used the `printk` there to print function name but no output is seen .But directly if I give printk very early in `start_kernel` function with `early_printk` enabled ,it works. I am calling it in `setup_arch()` function as `printk("%s %d",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__)` and it gives output correctly. But if I add the same in my `mcount` registered function, it does not display anything.

And can I use `sprint_symbol` in my `mcount` registered function before kallsyms is initialized.